# Generic function to be called from multiple triggers

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger, stored-functions

I have created a function and trigger to make use that the userId is uCased. The code is as followsL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stdUserId ()
RETURNS trigger AS $stdUserId$
    BEGIN        
        NEW.login_id = UPPER (TRIM (NEW.login_id));
        RETURN NEW;
    END;

$stdUserId$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS usersStdUserId ON users;

CREATE TRIGGER usersStdUserId BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON users
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE stdUserId (login_id);
```

Now I would like to alter the function to be usable with other triggers as in:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS user_rolesStdUserId ON user_roles;

CREATE TRIGGER user_rolesStdUserId BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON users
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE stdUserId (user_id);
```

I would like a generic approach as I have a number of tables to apply this function to. I would prefer to stay away from "IF table01 .. . ELSEIF table02 .. ."

Your assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Hard to impossible in PL/pgSQL. Try PL/PythonU.

Comment: I'd say - don't try, it's a bad idea. Instead, I'd think why the `id` columns are texts, not integers.